# Issue with Bitbucket user access

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I have created 2 Bit-bucket accounts by using 2 different email addresses.

Bit-bucket Repo 1 : 1234@gmail.com
Bit-bucket Repo 2 : 5678@gmail.com

I pulled the files using Repo 1 using Git Bash. At that time it asked me to enter the credentials and it worked correctly.
Then I closed the Git Bash and pulled the content from the Repo 2. At that time it didnt asked me the credentials. I was able to commit and pull the files without having any issue.

But after visiting to bitbucket.org and my project repository I was able to see these commits. (Refer Image 1)

[image]

It says 'harsha' not mapped to Bitbucket user. If its not mapped and if its not in repository permission list, **How it was able to push the changes in to the repository?**
Only the below users have access to the repository.

[image]

Comment: The committer info that git stores has nothing to do with authentication of bitbucket.

Comment: @1615903 How it was able to push the changes in to the repository if it has no access?

Comment: Please re-read the comment by @1615903. I can commit in my local repositories using the author name "Donald Duck", but to *push* to bitbucket or github I need a valid account on that site, which git also knows about, but again, this has nothing to do with what author name is recorded in the commits.